# Query a Encrypted field in SOSL

Tags: soql, sosl

I tried querying a Encrypted field in SOQL.
Gives an error:
encrypted field 'Email' cannot be filtered in a query call

Can i achieve it using SOSL??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the [Key limitations and their workarounds](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Key_limitations_and_their_workarounds) documentation.

You can use SOSL with an `IN EMAIL FIELDS` to get down to a small set of results and then an Apex look to refine to just the `Email` field (if you have multiple email fields and only want to match one of them).

Note that unit tests become more awkward because SOSL's index isn't built so you have to nominate the Id(s) that will be returned using `Test.setFixedSearchResults()`.

Comment: I have only one email field.